# Haskell: Procedurally generating level without slowing down

Tags: list, haskell, random, functional-programming

To better learn Haskell, I'm trying to basically build a variant of the well-known Indie Game [Super Hexagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Hexagon).

I am however having a problem with the level generation:

Right now, level generation is done by having a list containing all different "gauntlets" (patterns of walls, implemented as `[[Bool]]`,a variable number of rows, each containing `True` or `False` for ); these are the building blocks of the level. Using the getStdGen() number generator, I'm able to create an infinite list of gauntlets.

However, at a single time, we only want to render part of these. To keep track of if a gauntlet has already been passed or not, a second argument is introduced, containing the sum of the number of rows of all gauntlets before this one. (e.g,  `length (gauntletData currentRandomNumber) + snd $ randomGauntletList !! (n-1)`, where `randomGauntletList` has the type `[(Gauntlet,Integer)]`

The problem is in how this list is used in the rendering function and the updating function: `take 30 $ dropWhile (\(_,distance) -> currentDistance > distance) randomGauntletList`

The `dropWhile` results in the program taking longer and longer to return the current 'starting point' of the list, therefore slowing down the game after +- 30 seconds.

I'm out of my depth: Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Instead of storing a number in a reference and incrementing it, can you store the list of gauntlets in a reference and throw away the parts you've already passed?

Comment: @DanielWagner Maybe? How can a reference like that be made? How can I throw away parts of an infinite list?

Comment: Can you show some more code? I think @DanielWagner is suggesting that however you're holding the infinite list, you can drop the first element when you need to. This might mean having a recursive function call itself with the tail of the list, or it might mean modifying an `IORef` to take the head of the list it holds, or it might mean modifying the state in a `StateT`.... without seeing more code it's hard to make concrete suggestions.

Comment: @Qqwy: It should be pretty much analogous to however you are currently incrementing the `currentDistance`; but instead of using `(+)` to produce the new distance number, you would use `drop` to produce the new list of gauntlets.